# How do I handle an object moving in memory in the middle of a method?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, programming-languages, vm-implementation

I'm writing a VM in C++ for a programming language. The language is garbage collected, so I have instances of C++ classes that are allocated in the garbage collected heap. I'm using a copying collector, so when a GC happens, those objects are moved in memory. This means every pointer to that object needs to be updated. *Most* of those pointers are easy to handle, except for one tricky one: `this`. Consider:

```
class SomeObj : public Managed      // inheriting from this means it's on the GC heap
{
public:
  void method()
  {
    SomeObj* other = new SomeObj(); // could trigger a GC.
    printf("%d\n", someField);      // this points to wrong memory
  }

private:
  int someField;
};
```

If I am in the middle of an instance method of some object that lives on the GC heap, then `this` points to some GC memory. A collection can occur in the middle of this method. When that happens, the object gets moved to a new location. But, since we are in the middle of a method call, `this` is still pointing to the old wrong location.

I could get around this by not using instance methods on classes that are in managed memory, but I do like that the code is simpler this way. Are there any techniques for dealing with this?

Comment: `this` is just a hidden parameter to `method`. You can do what you like, say, you can `delete this;`, provided it was allocated appropriately and you don't access it (directly or indirectly) after that.

Comment: Note that it's not just `this` you need to worry about, it's any local pointer variable: `void SomeObj::method() { int *x = &m_int; do_something_that_causes_GC(); use(x); }`  (The compiler might put `x` in a register.)

Comment: If you have a binary tree (with 2 pointers per node), what code fixes all the pointers after a GC?  I think a copying collector requires introducing another level of indirection.

Comment: If you know where `this` is your GC can update it, it's either on the stack or in a register. Is the problem that you don't know where `this` is? If so then you have more serious problems I think.

Comment: Have you looked at the Boehm conservative garbage collector? It does GC but does not move objects and is widely used.

Comment: @RichieHindle, locals are a problem too, but I can address that with a `Handle` wrapper similar to what V8 does. I can add another level of indirection there. I can't do that with `this`.

Comment: @brianbeuning fixing pointers during a copying collection is pretty easy. See Cheney's algorithm. I already have a GC implemented and I'm not a fan of conservative GC or marking GC, so Boehm isn't appealing.

Comment: Maybe delaying the GC ? Save change informations and do change on GC at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Your GC needs to scan the stack and registers for pointers and fix them.  If your VM supports multi-threading, you need to suspend all threads while scanning their stacks. The 'this' pointer will be on the stack or in a register.

Since C++ does not supply type information for the stack you may have a hard time with something like

```
int i = 1000000;
char * p = new char[10]; // 0xF4240 = 1000000
```

Whatever method you are using to move other pointers is going to have the same problem.  At some point your code must convert handles to pointers and those pointers will need to be fixed.

Change C++ code like this

```
func()->method()
```

to look like

```
struct GCroot call123 = { func() };
call123.obj->method();
```

Multi-threading issue.  If you have code like this

```
struct GCroot obj123 = { /* .. */ };
obj123.ptr->x = obj123.ptr->x + 1;
```

it might generate pseudo assembly code like this

```
load r1, obj123.ptr
load r2, (r1)
add r2, 1
store (r1), r2
```

if another thread does a GC anytime between the first and last asm lines, how does r1 get fixed?

Comment: Other pointers don't have any problems here. I can wrap them in a structure that makes them visible roots and the GC will be able to find them directly.

Comment: @munificent So before calling any C++ method with a this pointer, wrap the this pointer in the same structure.

Comment: I don't see how to do that given that `this`'s semantics are baked into C++. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't believe that will work. Within the body of `method`, `this` will still be permanently bound to the original raw pointer to the object. What I could do is not use instance methods, and instead do `SomeClass::method(gc<SomeClass> self)`. But I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @munificent Is your VM multi-threaded?  Do you stop all threads when doing a GC?  See next edit for why this is important.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29069/discussion-between-brian-beuning-and-munificent)

Comment: Effectively does not work, because real compilers do not always keep `this`, but may decide to keep e.g. `this+8` or `this-8` instead.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have the time flexibility for chat. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce another level of indirection. I will use your example:

```
class SomeData : public Managed
{
 int someField;
};

class SomeObj : public Managed      // inheriting from this means it's on the GC heap
{
public:
  void method()
  {
    SomeObj* other = new SomeObj(); // could trigger a GC.
    printf("%d\n", someData->someField);      // this points to wrong memory
  }

private:
  SomeObjData* someData;
};
```

Note that every implementation of managed will to do that.

Comment: Doesn't this code have the same problem?  The GC moves the current object, `this` is no longer valid, the access of `someData` crashes.